# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined, but I've defined it discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, undefined, discord.js

I'm very very new to javascript, tell me if I'm doing anything wrong

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.guild) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}`) || message.author.bot) return;

  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}assignRole`)) {
    var parts = message.content.split(" ");
    const servguild = message.guild;
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    const role = servguild.role.find(r => r.name === parts[2]);
    member.roles.add(role);

  }
});
```

Comment: Read the error and which line it's pointing to. It's probably because you're trying to call the method `find` on `servguild.role.find`, meaning that `servguild.role` is undefined / not set. `console.log` what servguild is to inspect it to see if it has a role key. And in general get in the habit of reading errors and checking which lines they apply to.

Comment: @AndyRay I'll be honest I was trying your suggestions and I have absolutely no idea what I did, but it worked! I'll try and see what on earth changed. Thank you for your help! 
Edit: The only thing I changed was roles.find to roles.cache.find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here: `const role = servguild.role.find(r => r.name === parts[2]);` as the console log shows it.

With discord.js V12, you need to use cache and there is also a typo error in your code.

This code should work.

```js
const role = servguild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === parts[2]);
```